# Why is there no change in internal energy for an isothermal reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

This concept is used for deriving the relation :

Change in Entropy  =  $2.303 \,\ nR \,\ log_{10} (\frac{V_2}{V_1})$

But I don't understand why change in Internal energy = $0$.

Comment: I believe that your equation is not generally valid.  I think it is valid only for the ideal gas of particles that have no mutual force between them, and have no internal structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal Energy is a measure of the random motion of molecules. It depends only on temperature. By the definition of an isothermal process, which means than there is no change in temperature during the process the change in internal energy during an isothermal process must be zero. Note this only true for ideal gases with zero Vander Waals Forces between their molecules.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use the word *thermal energy* to describe the energy of random motion, and *internal* energy to be the sum of thermal energy and everything else.  There's no firm consensus on this.  I've seen *internal* energy used the way you use it, but in my opinion that's sloppy, and can lead to confusion such as the OP is experiencing.  [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/inteng.html), for example distinguishes between thermal and internal energy.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you have written is the change in entropy for an **ideal gas**.

An ideal gas is a collection of small, elastic balls which do not interact with their surroundings. Thus, the potential energy of the gas is zero due to the absence of any interactive potentials and thus, the energy of the gas is just its kinetic energy.

It can be shown that the kinetic energy of a macroscopic ideal gas, described above, depends only on it's temperature and not on the volume occupied by it (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble). Thus, the energy of the ideal gas, or the internal energy, which consists only of the kinetic energy of the small 'balls', does not depend on the volume of the gas, and only on the temperature. This is the reason why the change in internal energy is zero.